# float:left; and positioning in css

Tags: html, css

I have a project where I must make a menu that when you click on an icon shows you a div based on the icon you clicked.

I have the menu on top, and the divs that will be shown under it. 
In one specific div I am obligated to split it into two divs 50%. 
I created one div and added this `float:left` to make it go left, but instead it's gone down and I don't know what the problem is. The problem can be fixed if I nest this div in another div called cover, but I don't want to do that because it does not belong to that div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="about-menu">
    <li class="about-menu-item fol"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></li>
    <li class="about-menu-item abo"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
    <li class="about-menu-item int"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></li>
    <li class="about-menu-item gal"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></li>
    <li class="about-menu-item quo"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></li>
</div>
<div class="section-identity">
    <div class="faf">
        <div class="fers">
            <!-- this is the div that represents 50% but goes down -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.about-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(117,117,117,0.1);
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    margin:0;
}
.about-menu li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.about-menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #738ffe;
}
.about-menu li i {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #bdbdbd;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.section-identity {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 702;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
.faf {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 703;
}
.fers {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Here's the start of a bootply, I included font awesome but I can't see the icons. http://www.bootply.com/x5BKVvGbWD

Comment: What is on the left/right. Looks like a div insed an other div?

Comment: a `div` does not contain `li` children.  Your HTML is invalid.  Start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.about-menu li` and use `ul` tag instead of `div` tag for your `.about-menu` class.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nqwbzc6s/7/)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="about-menu">
    <li class="about-menu-item fol"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="about-menu-item abo"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="about-menu-item int"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="about-menu-item gal"><i class="fa fa-image"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="about-menu-item quo"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.about-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.1);
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; /* It was top: -140px; before, I've removed that and it's only for demo */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.about-menu li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
}
```